# Does LVM make data recovery easier or harder?

Tags: lvm, ext4, data-recovery, nixos

Does LVM make data recovery on ext 4 easier or harder? I have to consider the risk of hdd failure. Thanks.

I am going to install some Linux distribution (e.g. NixOS) on a laptop. It is already partitioned with LVM.
Nothing on the HDD is valuable.
I can overwrite the whole hdd or find a way to reuse the LVM volumes.

Comment: Why worry about data recovery, when you could just make backups?

Comment: because I don't have a big enough backup device

Comment: I'd recommend a larger backup device, then.  Data recovery is inherently a mostly-manual, incomplete, trouble-prone, hit-or-miss operation, whereas backups, done correctly, come very close to 100% recovery. It's an imperfect analogy, but it's somewhat akin to wondering whether one is more likely to survive a car wreck in a 2-door or a 4-door sedan, given that one chooses not to use a safety belt. It's probably a better use of time to adopt safer driving habits.

Answer (score 2):

If you are considering the risk of hard disk failure, you are going to back up, otherwise you are not considering the risk of hard disk failure. To answer the question, I would think LVM would make it harder, unless you have an odd partitioning scheme. LVM adds extra complexity, extra complexity almost always makes data recovery harder. However, the difference is most likely minimal, if your HDD itself fails it wont matter what you're using, it will be just as hard to recover data either way.